# Use system() with a variable in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, system, qstring

I want to run a system command in Qt such as:

```
system("echo 50 > //sys//class//pwm-sunxi//pwm0//duty_percent")
```

Now the problem is, I want to use a variable for the 50 from the code above so that I can use a slider to change the values

if it any helps, I am running *Linux Debian* distro on a Cubieboard A20

I've tried using

```
system("echo "INTtoString(variable)" > //sys//class//pwm-sunxi//pwm0//duty_percent")
```

but it shows the error

expected `)` before `INTtoString`

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out `QProcess` for Qt way to run shell commands. And indeed, prefer writing to file directly, in Qt app by using `QFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, I would use QFile for this writing operation.

If you really wish to stick with the current concept, I would personally use two things:

1) [QString's arg() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) to create the string.

2) [qPrintable(myQString)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable) to get the const char* back for the execution.

So, I would be writing something like this:

```
QString myString = QString("echo %1 > /sys/class/pwm-sunxi/pwm0/duty_percent").arg(INTtoString(variable));
system(qPrintable(myString));
```

But really, here is a much better approach:

```
QFile file("/sys/class/pwm-sunxi/pwm0/duty_percent");
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text
              | QIODevice::Truncate | QIODevice::Unbuffered))
    if (file.write(INTtoString(variable)) != 2)
        qDebug() << "Failed to write all:" << file.errorString();
else
    qDebug() << "Failed to open:" << file.errorString();
// No need to close as it will be done automatically by the RAII feature
```

Please also note that the double forward slashes are superfluous, then.

Comment: Isn't QFile buffered? So should either flush or close to detect error from actual writing system call. (And not down voter.)

Comment: @hyde: close will be called automatically when you run out of the scope, but I agree that writing to the sysfs is better with unbuffered mode, so I added that to the flags, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the shell call, just use a `QFile`:

```
void change_duty_percent(int value)
{
  QFile duty_pc("/sys/class/pwm-sunxi/pwm0/duty_percent");
  duty_pc.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate);
  duty_pc.write(QString::number(value));
  duty_pc.close();
}
```

If you do want to use the shell, make sure you convert to a `char*` correctly by using a separate instance of `QByteArray`:

```
QString command = QString("echo %1 > /sys/class/pwm-sunxi/pwm0/duty_percent").arg(value);
QByteArray commandBA(command.toLocal8Bit());
system(commandBA.data());
```

Comment: Not checking against errors, also close is unnecesary... The byte array is also needless. It is also not using INTtoString what the OP showed in his code.

Comment: Also, constData() would be better than data() here since it is not modified, but qPrintable already does all that boilerplate...

Comment: As @hyde mentioned in the comment under my answer, it is also better to write the sysfs in unbuffered mode just like write(2). People usually do not use fwrite(3) for that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The `QByteArray` is not needless, see [How can I convert a QString to char* and vice versa?](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa), particularly the line "it is necessary to store the bytearray before you call data() on it". Use of `qPrintable` is valid, but you have to be careful to never store the return value.

Comment: 1) Try to print out `QString s = "foo"; printf("%s", s.toLocal8Bit().constData());` You may be surprised because it will just work without explicit interim QBA. I would suggest to fix the wikipage since it is also supposed to work. 2) There is no storage for the return value here, so it is meant for cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

create a QString to hold the command:

```
QString command = QString("echo %1 > //sys//class//pwm-sunxi//pwm0//duty_percent");
```

then you can use `arg` to replace %1 with another value:

```
system(command.arg(50).toLocal8Bit().constData());
```

Comment: This answer also works if anybody still wondering.Thanks ratchet freak but I think I'm going to use the QFile method